# How can I recursively change the permissions of specific files into a list of directories?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have several directories and have files with an extention *.fastq and I want to change the permissions to only read for all users. Is there any way to do it without having to go into each directory? I tried with a for loop but it doesn't work.

```
for i in $(ls -d */); do chmod -w *.fastq; done
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try find(1).

```
find _dir_ -name '*.fastq' -exec chmod a-wx {} \;
```

This will process all files in *dir* and its subdirectories where names end in .fastq.  It will do a chmod on those files to remove write and execute permissions for all users, groups and others.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should work, but we should remind that every user who has root-privileges could bypass the permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. The command worked perfect.